# Estou com um erro no NetBeans não consigo fazer expressão lambda

Tags: java, netbeans

Já mexi alterei o JAVA_HOME: para C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4 mas mesmo assim continua com erro estou com o NetBeans 8.0.2 e 11.0 mas o erro persiste.

Esse o erro:

lambda expression not expected here  lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu netbeans está setado com o jdk 1.6 você tem que alterar no conf do netbeans:

Procura o folder onde o netbeans está instalado
C:\Program Files\NetBeans x.x\etc\netbeans.conf

Altera a variavel abaixo apontando para o jdk 1.8 que você tiver ai
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8xxxxx"

Comment: Obrigado consegui arrumar